# Is fusion table suitable as website database?

Tags: database, google-fusion-tables

I am a huge fan of Google fusion tables. I want to know that is it possible to use fusion table as database to create dynamic webpages? If so can anyone give sample links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but this is a very bad idea.
Let's see what are the pros and cons of using FT as db layer of a website:

Pros:

- You can use basic geographic functions in your DB. I have to say most common databases have spatial extensions either built-in or provided as a plugin
- You can easily integrate a Google Map in your webpage displaying geo data from FT.
- No setup costs

Cons:

- Awful response times as [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1246898/jack) highlighted in his answer
- You are limited to a 0.5 request/sec on average. This is true for INSERT/UPDATE statements. Without throttling you will get lots of 500 errors back.
- Limited predicates in the WHERE clause. The case of the missing 'OR' !!
- Lack of the ability to create complex WHERE clauses.
- FT uses a NoSQL approach. Forget your typed columns.
- No relations or foreign key constraints. However you can join tables on attribute values.
- Using triggers/stored procedures or any common DB concept except views is not possible.
- Aggregate functions have really bad performace.
- So far no ORM supports FT that i know of. Some people think ORM's are useless but anyway this is something to consider.

And this is far from a complete list. In a nutshell: FT is not designed for what you're trying to use it. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically this could be possible. I would have serious concerns about using this type of architecture for a dynamic webpage because of the Fusion Tables response times when making a request.  Fusion table responses can take anywhere from 100 ms to 1 s (in my experience with them) and this inconsistant response time works for building a map or chart on a page, but I believe could be troublesome if using to store data for dynamic webpages.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. But I think for webpages with small (limited) dataset this may be a great feature. If you have sample code please share me.